# list inheritance ? sql and class

Tags: mysql, sql, database, class, inheritance

I'm using MySQL and I got three Tables : `Interlocuteur`, `Individu`and `Structure`

Basically, `Interlocuteur` means Client, `Individu` means Person and `Structure` means Group.

An `Interlocuteur`(Client) must be either an `Individu`(Person) or a `Structure`(Group)

**However several `Interlocuteur`(Client) can work in a single `Structure`(Group)**

So i made theese three classes but i'm not sure with `Structure` :

```
public class Interlocuteur
{
    public virtual int idInterlocuteur { get; set; }
    public virtual string nomInterlocuteur { get; set; }
    public virtual string prenomInterlocuteur { get; set; }
    public virtual string telInterlocuteur { get; set; }
    public virtual string mailInterlocuteur { get; set; }
    }

public class Individu
{

    public virtual Interlocuteur interlocuteur { get; set; }

    public virtual int numIndividu { get; set; }
    public virtual float distanceSiege { get; set; }
    public virtual string adresseIndividu { get; set; }
    public virtual string cpIndividu { get; set; }
    public virtual string villeIndividu { get; set; }
    public virtual string planAcces { get; set; }
    public virtual string infosSupplementaire { get; set; }

}

public class Structure
{

public virtual ISet<Interlocteur> lesInterlocuteurs { get; set; }

public virtual int numStructure { get; set; }
public virtual float distanceSiege { get; set; }
public virtual string cpStructure { get; set; }
public virtual string denominationSociale { get; set; }
public virtual string adresseStructure { get; set; }
public virtual string villeStructure { get; set; }
public virtual string planAcces { get; set; }
public virtual string infoSupplementaire { get; set; }
public virtual TypeStructure typeStructure { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not sure about the list for inheritance, is it right or should I add a joining table/class within `Interlocteur` and `Structure` and make inherit the joining class ?

**note : I'm using nhibernate**

Comment: I am thinking client -> group -> person. Where the arrow points to a subclass.

Comment: but person is not a child of group, a client is either a group or a person. not both.

Comment: Yo maybe client --> person --> group  i think it can work

Comment: I hope it can. I was looking at this from a Java point of view. Which was probably off. lol

Comment: no in the end i can't, because multiple person can work in a structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that you can't talk about inheritance if you need a list.
I just created a joining class and everything works fine